# Converting help: __asm__ __volatile__

Tags: c, assembly, d, inline-assembly

I would like to port C's outb function to D.

```
static __inline void outb (unsigned char value, unsigned short int port)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("outb %b0,%w1"
                          :
                          :
                         "a" (value),
                          "Nd" (port));
}
```

This is D version.

```
extern(C) 
{
    void outb (ubyte value, ushort port)
    {
        // I couldn't figure out this part
   }

}
```

These are some links about the subject.

**D Inline Assembler**

http://dlang.org/iasm.html

**GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO**

http://ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

But I don't know assembly language so I need some help. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `outb` instruction should only be called as `outb %al, %dx` where `%al` is the value and `%dx` is the port.

D uses Intel syntax for x86, as opposed to GNU assembler which uses the AT&T syntax by default. The corresponding Intel syntax would be `out dx, al`, and corresponding code in D would look like:

```
void outb (ubyte value, ushort port)
{
    asm {
        mov AL, value;
        mov DX, port;
        out DX, AL;
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to write the assembly at all, because druntime has the [`core.bitop.outp`](http://dlang.org/phobos/core_bitop.html#outp) function which perform the same instruction.

```
void outb (ubyte value, ushort port)
{
    import core.bitop;
    outp(port, value);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that's probably tripping you up is that the D compiler's supported list of opcodes does not include `outb`, as specified by the C function you provided. After some digging, I've found out that `outb` is a more specific name for the general opcode `out`. `outb` indicates that the first argument to the opcode will be contained in a byte register (as opposed to `outw` and `outl`, which indicate a first argument size of, respectively, a word and a double word), however, the D compiler uses the opcode `out` for all of the operations, and determines which specific opcode to write based on the size of the argument you specify.

With that out of the way, the next thing to do is to convert the GCC syntax to D syntax. According to the GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO, the code you provided uses the extended assembly syntax:

```
asm ( assembler template 
    : output operands                  /* optional */
    : input operands                   /* optional */
    : list of clobbered registers      /* optional */
    );
```

Looking at your template, the function specifies one assembly instruction (`outb`) with two arguments, the first being a byte (`%b0`) and the second being a word or short integer (`%w0`).

The tricky bit about the input arguments list is the string that prefixes each of your function parameters. These, according to the HOWTO, are called constraints. They're essentially rules that GCC must follow in using the parameters as arguments to the provided assembly instructions. The constraint `"a"` applied to the `value` parameter indicates that the contents of the variable must be placed in either register `eax`, `ax`, or `al` depending on the size of the variable. The constraint on the `port` variable, `"Nd"`, indicates first that the value is in the range of 0-255, and second, that the value must be placed in either register `edx`, `dx`, or `dl`, again, based upon the size of the variable.

The D compiler doesn't offer as much help with variables in assembly blocks as GCC does; in D's inline assembler, you'll need to specifically move the values of the parameters into the proper registers. For `outb`, these registers are `dx` and `al`. Following D's inline assembly syntax, you can move the variables and call the `out` opcode as follows:

```
asm
{
    MOV AL, value;
    MOV DX, port;
    OUT DX, AL;
}
```

Note that, because GCC uses the AT&T assembler syntax, and D uses the Intel assembler syntax, the order of the arguments provided to `OUT` is reversed.